# Opportunity Contact role mandatory is not working and error message is not populated

Tags: apex, trigger

```
  if (!stageNewCheck.contains(opp.StageName) && fieldHasChanged(opp, Opportunity.StageName)){
            System.debug('opportunityNewStageMap: ' );
            opportunityNewStageMap.put(opp.Id, opp);
            System.debug('opportunityNewStageMap: ' +opportunityNewStageMap);
        }
if (!opportunityNewStageMap.isEmpty()) {
        List<Opportunity> OppOcrList =[SELECT Id,
                                    (SELECT Id, Role FROM OpportunityContactRoles WHERE Role = null LIMIT 1)
                                    FROM Opportunity
                                    WHERE Id IN :opportunityNewStageMap.keySet() ];
        System.debug('OppOcrList: ' +OppOcrList);
        if (!OppOcrList.isEmpty()) {
            System.debug('OppOcrList====: ' +OppOcrList);
            for(Opportunity oppWithRoles:OppOcrList){
                if (!oppWithRoles.OpportunityContactRoles.isEmpty()) {
                    System.debug(System.Label.Opportunity_Contact_Role_Mandatory_Error);
                    Opportunity opp = opportunityMap.get(oppWithRoles.Id);
                    System.debug('opp : ' +opp);
                    opp.addError(System.Label.Opportunity_Contact_Role_Mandatory_Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Adderror should display when the opportunity does not have an opportunity contact role. can someone help me what the issue with this code and why the error is not populating?

Comment: Which opportunities are stored in `opportunityMap`? Are they from trigger context? or did you get them via soql, then put them in the map?

Comment: It's from trigger context

Comment: You say "Adderror should display when the opportunity does not have an opportunity contact role." but actually what your code is checking is "Adderror should display when the opportunity has an opportunity contact role record with an empty role field.". Which of the 2 is your actual requirement?

Comment: Actual requirement is when opportunity does not have an role it should display error, I check with oppWithRoles.OpportunityContactRoles.isEmpty() too. but did not work, is there any other place have issue